# Is there a dequeue function for vert.x AMQP to clear the message?

Tags: java, amqp, vert.x, enqueue

From the AmqpReceiver, i am able to print out the enqueue message, but how do I dequeue or clear the message from the queue?

```
amqpClient.createReceiver("my-queue",
        done -> {
            if (done.failed()) {
                done.cause().printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Unable to create receiver");
            } else {
                final AmqpReceiver receiver = done.result();
                receiver.address();
                receiver
                        .exceptionHandler(t -> {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        })
                        .handler(msg -> {
                            System.out.println("Message: " + msg.bodyAsJsonObject().toString());
                        });

                receiver.connection().close(ar -> {
                });
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: What have you tried (code) until now? This encourage to answer...

Comment: i added the code,  actually i refer to this link https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-amqp-client/java/, but just got stuck that the message not being dequeue.

Answer (score 0):

By default the receiver is going to accept and settle the message so you (as indicated in the [docs](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-proton/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/proton/ProtonReceiver.java#L68)) shouldn't need to do anything unless you've altered the configuration such that it doesn't accept and settle for you.  If you desire a different disposition or want to control settlement then you can do so by calling the [methods](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-proton/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/proton/ProtonDelivery.java#L35) in the delivery you received.

There is some more detailed explanations in the vertx-proton example code [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-proton/blob/master/src/test/java/io/vertx/proton/example/HelloWorld.java).